# Error installing GlassFish Tools on eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, glassfish, java-ee-6

The eclipse foundation has archived the **GlassFish Tools 1.0.0 and 1.01**.
It is no longer possible to install GlassFish Tools either through *Eclipse MarketPlace* or through *Install new Software* on the eclipse help menu. Both attempts lead to the error `No repository found at https://download.eclipse.org/glassfish-tools/1.0.0/repository/.`

[image]

[image]

Thank you for all your suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

After some research, I was able to install GlassFish Tools on eclipse.

Although eclipse has archived the GlassFish Tools dependencies, Oracle has maintained them and offers documentation for installing them.

Several links are proposed but, I will just show you the ones that worked for me.

1. Follow this link for the documentation
   https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/oepe/12.2.1.8/oxygen/repository/
2. Copy this link to download the dependencies
   http://download.oracle.com/otn_software/oepe/12.2.1.8/oxygen/repository/dependencies/

Following the link of the documentation (1)

1. Open Eclipse and select the Install New Software menu item under the Help menu.
2. Copy and paste this URL (2) http://download.oracle.com/otn_software/oepe/12.2.1.8/oxygen/repository/dependencies/ into the Work with text box, then press ENTER.
3. Once the repository is loaded, the available features should show up in the table.

[image]

4. Select **Eclipse GlassFish Tools**, click on next button and follow the wizard to install them.

The installation is a bit slow but it works.

Comment: thanks i installed  Eclipse GlassFish Tools